# Create pandas dataframe from list of lists, but there are different seperators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of lists:

```
     [['1', 'Toy Story (1995)', "Animation|Children's|Comedy"],
     ['2', 'Jumanji (1995)', "Adventure|Children's|Fantasy"],
     ['3', 'Grumpier Old Men (1995)', 'Comedy|Romance']]
```

I want to end up with a pandas dataframe with these columns.

```
cols = ['MovieID', 'Name', 'Year', 'Adventure', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Romance']
```

For the `'Adventure', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Romance'` columns, the data will be 1 or 0.

I've tried:

```
for row in movies_list:
    for element in row:
        if '|' in element:
            element = element.split('|')
```

However nothing happens to the original list.. Completely stumped here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor with [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
L = [['1', 'Toy Story (1995)', "Animation|Children's|Comedy"],
     ['2', 'Jumanji (1995)', "Adventure|Children's|Fantasy"],
     ['3', 'Grumpier Old Men (1995)', 'Comedy|Romance']]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['MovieID','Name','Data'])


df1 = df['Data'].str.get_dummies()
print (df1)
   Adventure  Animation  Children's  Comedy  Fantasy  Romance
0          0          1           1       1        0        0
1          1          0           1       0        1        0
2          0          0           0       1        0        1
```

For columns `Name` and `Year` need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) for remove trailing `)`, also `Year` is converted to `int`s.

```
df[['Name','Year']] = df['Name'].str.split('\s\(', expand=True)
df['Year'] = df['Year'].str.rstrip(')').astype(int)
```

Last remove column `Data` and add `df1` to original by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.drop('Data', axis=1).join(df1)
print (df)
  MovieID              Name  Year  Adventure  Animation  Children's  Comedy  \
0       1         Toy Story  1995          0          1           1       1   
1       2           Jumanji  1995          1          0           1       0   
2       3  Grumpier Old Men  1995          0          0           0       1   

   Fantasy  Romance  
0        0        0  
1        1        0  
2        0        1
```

Comment: Thanks again jezrael!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version, not good enough for one line answer, but hope it helps you!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['1', 'Toy Story (1995)', "Animation|Children's|Comedy"],
     ['2', 'Jumanji (1995)', "Adventure|Children's|Fantasy"],
     ['3', 'Grumpier Old Men (1995)', 'Comedy|Romance']]
cols = ['MovieID', 'Name', 'Year', 'Adventure', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Romance']
final = []
for x in data:
    output = []
    output.append(x[0])
    output.append(x[1].split("(")[0].lstrip().rstrip())
    output.append(x[1].split("(")[1][:4])
    for h in ['Adventure', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Romance']:
        output.append(h in x[2])
    final.append(output)

df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns=cols)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  MovieID              Name  Year  Adventure  Children  Comedy  Fantasy  \
0       1         Toy Story  1995      False      True    True    False   
1       2           Jumanji  1995       True      True   False     True   
2       3  Grumpier Old Men  1995      False     False    True    False   

   Romance  
0    False  
1    False  
2     True
```